# How to add multiple user inputs in Python

Tags: python

I'm just starting out with Python and I'm working on a program for an assignment. The description is that it's for for an electronic device that will be attached to a grocery cart. When the shopper begins shopping, the device will ask the shopper their budget, which is the maximum amount the shopper would like to spend. It will then ask the shopper to input the cost of each item that they place in the cart. Each time something is added to the cart, the device will add the cost of the item to a running total, or sum, of the cost of all the items in the cart. Once the cost of all the items goes over budget, it will alert the shopper that they have spent too much money.

I've mapped out the code and kind of figured out everything I need to do. But I can't get it to add the user's multiple inputs correctly. Ideally it should add the users first input with their second, and third, etc and stop when the user enters ALL DONE.

Here's my code so far. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated!

```
budget = 0
itemCost = 0
cartTotal = 0

print ("Hello! Welcome to the best grocery store ever!")
budget = int (input ("What is your budget for today? "))
itemCost = int (input ("Please tell me the cost of the most recent item your cart. Print ALL DONE to quit " ))

while itemCost != "All DONE" and cartTotal <= budget:
    itemCost = int (input ("Please tell me the cost of the most recent item your cart. Print ALL DONE to quit " )) #works
    cartTotal = itemCost + itemCost
    print ("OK, the items in your cart cost a total of ", cartTotal) 
    print ("Your budget is ", budget, " you have spent ", cartTotal, " you have ", budget - cartTotal, " left over.")
else:
    print ("You are a horrible budgeter!")
```

Comment: You are not allowing for a quantity of more than 1

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So what I've done is checked if the input is a number (.isdigit) and if it is, added that to a running total. Your code wouldn't accept 'ALL DONE' because it would only accept integer inputs, so I've changed that too. Finally, I've changed the budget to a float, because that makes more sense with money I would have though. Hope this helps! EDIT: It doesn't like floats as a cost, but other than that I've tested it and it seems to work

```
budget = 0
itemCost = 0
cartTotal = 0

on = "TRUE"

print("Hello! Welcome to the best grocery store ever!")
budget = float(input("What is your budget for today?"))
while on == "TRUE" :
    itemCost = input("Please tell me the cost of the most recent item in your cart. Type ALL DONE to quit. ")
    if itemCost == "ALL DONE" :
        on = "FALSE"

    elif itemCost.isdigit() :
        cartTotal += float(itemCost)
        if cartTotal < budget :
            print("Ok, the items in your cart cost a total of ", cartTotal)
            print ("Your budget is ", budget, " you have spent ", cartTotal, " you have ", budget - cartTotal, " left over.")
        else :
            print("You are a horrible budgeter!")
            break
    else :
        print("Invalid entry!") #If neither a number nor ALL DONE was entered, this happens
        continue
```